# Win10 SATA disk drive disappears, but to knoppix it is ther with a "remove_hiberfile" mount

Tags: hard-drive, boot, sata

Tearing my hair out for about a month with this. Gigabyte mobo, win10 upgrade from win8.  SATA WD 1TB drive (tho has happened with other SATA).  Last time around, I got a win10 install restored to a 1TB SATA just fine [using win7 backup/restore! from a win10 install using an IDE drive].  Used it for about 5 days, then bang! reboot, and no SATA drive appears, even on Windows recovery disk, no sda.  The BIOS just hangs at "AHCI drive init....." and eventually times out - no SATA drive to be found.  When I boot knoppix, I can see the drive, and even mount it, warned by Knoppix to add "-o remove_hiberfile"  Then I see the drive and all files - but still not there when I boot win10.   This has happened twice at least.  Happened with TWO Gbyte mobos, which BLOWs my mind [updated all drivers on GA-78LMT. This is a GA-880GM-UD2H]  What am I doing to cause this?? And how do I fix this!  A month of googling with lots of hints, but no clear answers. I even when thru the BCDboot/bcdedit etc stuff on winrecovery - don't want to venture there again until I undertand this.

Comment: Second time I booted Knoppix, it could NOT find the drive.  Win10 still stalls at BIOS AHCI drive init....  I could believe a bad disk drive/SATA chip, but this has happened with two mobos, two SATA drives.  I have swapped power supply/SATA cables.  Nothing left.  Same AMD Athlon, but surely not?

Comment: Tried gparted live CD, still no sda.  Booted again, defaulted BIOS, it asked me to set SATA as AHCI... OK.  This time it booted windows OK.  The only thing I ever changed in the BIOS was to get it to boot USB CDROM first.  Hmmm.... something fishy about BIOS.  Dare I try repeating this?